# Tomcat start failure probably due to Linux network setup: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: java, linux, networking

I can't start tomcat due to the pasted stack trace, and I don't believe the answer is in Java.
I've tried changing ports and confirmed that another port (8005) also fails with the same error message.
How do I verify that my linux network setup allows Java to use ports?

EDIT2: It appears this box has been the victim of an intrusion.  I believe it makes sense to flag this post for moderator to close since a compromised box can't be expected to behave normally.  Thank you everyone for your time and effort.

EDIT:
there is a possibility that corruption of packages in /bin is responsible.  I had to update the a few with up2date.

EXTRA INFO:

Re: similar questions, I've eliminated the JVM_BIND possibility by checking netstat.

ping localhost simply hangs:

```
$ ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
-- no responses ---
--- localhost ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 8000ms
```

ping google works:

```
$ ping google.com
PING google.com (74.125.225.228) 56(84) bytes of data.
-- responses removed ---
--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.389/1.417/1.443/0.048 ms, pipe 2
```

the exception:

```
    SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[8036]:
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:373)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:662)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:614)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Jun 5, 2013 12:49:05 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8035
Jun 5, 2013 12:49:05 PM org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector pause
SEVERE: Protocol handler pause failed
java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument or cannot assign requested address
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.unLockSocket(ChannelSocket.java:492)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.pause(ChannelSocket.java:289)
        at org.apache.jk.server.JkMain.pause(JkMain.java:725)
        at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.pause(JkCoyoteHandler.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.pause(Connector.java:1029)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:566)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:744)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:648)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina$CatalinaShutdownHook.run(Catalina.java:692)
```

Comment: Are you running with SELinux enabled?

Comment: nope: $ sestatus
SELinux status:         disabled

Comment: I've had the problem where one of our system engineers did not enable "lo" interface. It took me a while to realize this, but failing to ping 127.0.0.1 was the first step towards right direction.

Answer (score 9):

Seems to me that your [/etc/host](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/chap9sec95.html) configuration is not correct. Are you able to ping 127.0.0.1? Also make sure you have following line in your host file

**/etc/host**

```
127.0.0.1           localhost
```

.

Please check if your "[The Loopback Interface](http://linux.about.com/od/lna_guide/a/gdelna47t00.htm)" is setup correctly.

Comment: It does contain that entry, but as I said in main description when I try to ping it, I get no responses.

Comment: You don't get ping response because your system is not able to resolve hostname "localhost" to any valid reachable IP Address. Add above mentioned entry and restart your network or system. Also make sure you are able to ping "127.0.0.1"

Comment: I can't ping 127.0.0.1 even though the entry is in the host file.

Comment: You have issue with your "The Loopback Interface".

Answer (score 2):

"java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address" suggests another instance of Tomcat didn't shutdown properly and is still using the port you assigned to tomcat.

Comment: I have confirmed that it is not JVM_BIND, there is no java/tomcat instance running.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from user1628502 is correct.Another instance is running and which is using this address, Kill that process and try to run the server again. Are you running as root? then all the port and resources used by the server will be unbinded and released automatically upon server close/shutdown. And in case of user , when you are not shutting down the server properly, the address remains to be binded, that might be your pblm.

Restart system & Try to run as root user

Comment: nothing like that is happening: [devuser@server ~]$ ps -ef | grep -i java
devuser 18463 18419  0 15:03 pts/2    00:00:00 grep -i java
[devuser@server ~]$ ps -ef | grep -i tomcat
devuser 18465 18419  0 15:03 pts/2    00:00:00 grep -i tomcat

Comment: 'tomcat' is the file name you use to run server? Did you tried restart & root ?

Comment: no it shows up as java blah blah, but i grepped both tomcat and java to show you that nothing shows up, as root.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already verified that no other process is using the same port as configured for Tomcat, you need to verify your network configuration now.

Check that your `/etc/host` file does not contain multiple entries for `localhost`. If it does, verify that the IP addresses listed are actually assigned to your machine. If not, either remove or update those entries with your current IP address.

Comment: Only one entry is is listed for localhost, 127.0.0.1.